# unable to use ScreenRecorder class in my javaFX project

Tags: java, javafx

I am working to develop screen recording application using JavaFX.
I am added some dependency to provide me library to implement screen recording, but unable to use [**ScreenRecorder**](https://github.com/stephenc/monte-screen-recorder) in my program.

This is my **pom.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>VideoRecorder</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>VideoRecorder</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>      </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
      <version>17.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
      <version>17.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
                                    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.stephenc.monte/monte-screen-recorder -->


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.agomezmoron</groupId>
      <artifactId>screen-recorder</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
      <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.example.videorecorder/com.example.videorecorder.HelloApplication</mainClass>
              <launcher>app</launcher>
              <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
              <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
              <noManPages>true</noManPages>
              <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
              <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
          </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>screen-recorder</id>
      <name>Java screen recorder library by agomezmoron</name>
      <url>https://raw.github.com/agomezmoron/screen-recorder/mvn-repo</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

this is my Screen recorder class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.Screen;

import com.github.stephenc.monte.ScreenRecorder;

import java.io.File;

public class ScreenRecorderApp extends Application {

    private ScreenRecorder screenRecorder;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button startButton = new Button("Start Recording");
        Button stopButton = new Button("Stop Recording");

        startButton.setOnAction(event -> startRecording());
        stopButton.setOnAction(event -> stopRecording());

        VBox root = new VBox(10, startButton, stopButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Screen Recorder");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        screenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(
                new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads/recording.mp4"),
                Screen.getPrimary()
        );
        screenRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (screenRecorder != null) {
            screenRecorder.stop();
            screenRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // Ensure that the screen recorder is stopped when the application closes
        stopRecording();
        Platform.exit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my **module-info.java** file

```
module com.example.videorecorder {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.desktop;


    opens com.example.videorecorder to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.videorecorder;
}
```

Unable to import this package:

```
import com.github.stephenc.monte.ScreenRecorder;
```

So provide me related changes.

Comment: i am using java 17

Comment: yes i have module-info.java added in code and i am using intellij idea

Comment: i have no idea about this

Comment: What happens when you add a `requires` clause for the package?

Comment: for witch package? @trashgod

Comment: show Module not found error @Abra

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect the new results and the error you get.

Comment: in module-info if i add requires com.github.stephenc.monte;
i am not able to add this,on this line show module not found:com.github.stephenc.monte @trashgod

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your [`dependency`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.stephenc.monte/monte-screen-recorder/0.7.7.0), but you might check your local repository. So others see what you see, please [edit] your question to reflect the new results and the error you get.

Comment: directly i dont see any error

see i have added this dependency     
```<dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.agomezmoron</groupId>
      <artifactId>screen-recorder</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.3</version>
    </dependency>```
for use thi class in my code ScreenRecorder but i am not able to import this class in my application @trashgod

Comment: You `require` *modules*, not *packages*. You need to know the *module name* for the module that contains the packages you are using. If the library you are using is modular, the module name will be declared in its own `module-info.java` and should be included in its documentation. If it's not modular, the module name will be an automatic name derived from the name of the jar file. See this good [introduction to the module system](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).

Comment: That ScreenRecorder project has no module descriptor, so the module is an automatic module.  The module name which your module-info must require will be the `Automatic-Module-Name` manifest attribute of the ScreenRecorder project’s .jar file; if no such attribute exists, the module name will be based the name of the .jar file itself.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#of(java.nio.file.Path...).

Comment: so how to solve my issues? @James_D