# “module not found” error despite “requires” in my module-info.java in JavaFX application

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on JavaFX project for screen recording. I need to record entire screen. I use [`monte-screen-recorder`](https://github.com/stephenc/monte-screen-recorder) [*dependency*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.stephenc.monte/monte-screen-recorder/0.7.7.0).

This is my **pom.xml** file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.screenRecorder</groupId>
    <artifactId>ScreenRecorder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ScreenRecorder</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JavaCV dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jcodec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcodec-javase</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JavaFX dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.stephenc.monte/monte-screen-recorder -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
            <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.kokorin.jaffree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaffree</artifactId>
            <version>2023.09.10</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Compiler Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- JavaFX Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.screenrecorder.screenrecorder.HelloApplication
                            </mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my application code:

```java
package com.screenrecorder;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.monte.media.Format;
import org.monte.media.FormatKeys;
import org.monte.media.math.Rational;
import org.monte.screenrecorder.ScreenRecorder;

import java.awt.*;

import static org.monte.media.FormatKeys.MediaTypeKey;
import static org.monte.media.VideoFormatKeys.ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE;

public class ScreenRecorderApp extends Application {

    private ScreenRecorder screenRecorder;
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button startButton = new Button("Start Recording");
        startButton.setOnAction(event -> startRecording());

        Button stopButton = new Button("Stop Recording");
        stopButton.setOnAction(event -> stopRecording());

        VBox root = new VBox(10, startButton, stopButton);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Screen Recorder");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        try {
            GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                    .getDefaultScreenDevice()
                    .getDefaultConfiguration();

            screenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(gc, null, new Format(MediaTypeKey, FormatKeys.EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
                    FormatKeys.FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(15)), new Format(MediaTypeKey, FormatKeys.EncodingKey, "black", FormatKeys.FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)),
                    null);
            screenRecorder.start();

            isRecording = true;
            System.out.println("Recording started...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if (isRecording && screenRecorder != null) {
            try {
                screenRecorder.stop();
                System.out.println("Recording stopped...");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            isRecording = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my `module-info.java` file:

```java
module com.screenrecorder {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires jcodec.javase;
    requires monte.screen.recorder;

    opens com.screenrecorder to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.screenrecorder;

}
```

When I run my application, I get this error:

```
java: module not found: monte.screen.recorder
```

i don't know why i am facing this error.
what i need to change in my code?

i am trying some changes but still facing same error.

try to use different library but i don't find any one.

Comment: Where is the monte.screen.recorder module defined? It looks like it was released before modules were common.

Comment: The correct module name will be based on the name of the .jar file.  See [the ModuleFinder documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#of(java.nio.file.Path...)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [_Unable to use ScreenRecorder class in my JavaFX project_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78033708/230513)

Comment: As an aside, I never recommend writing `import java.awt.*;` in a JavaFX application.  There are too many names in AWT that clash with names in JavaFX, which can lead to much confusion when they are not fully qualified in code that shares classes with the same simple names.

Answer (score 3):

#### Why you *cannot* use the screen recorder jar as a module

**The reason you can't use the screen recorder jar as a module is because the jar contains classes that are not in any named Java package**.

Even if you require a valid module name, there are other reasons why the jar might fail to function as a module (e.g. [package conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358084/package-conflicts-with-automatic-modules-in-java-9)), because the jar was never created to be used as a module.  It might still work (or it might not).

To test some of these aspects, you can use the `jar` tool to get module information from the jar:

```
jar --describe-module --file ~/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/monte/monte-screen-recorder/0.7.7.0/monte-screen-recorder-0.7.7.0.jar
```

And you will receive output similar to the following:

```
Unable to derive module descriptor for: ~/.m2/repository/com/github/stephenc/monte/monte-screen-recorder/0.7.7.0/monte-screen-recorder-0.7.7.0.jar
ScreenRecorder.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
```

#### Determining the correct module name for your screen recorder dependency

Understand how [automatic modules work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module).  As others have noted in the comments, use the correct name for the module.

As the jar has no `module-info.java` or `Automatic-Module-Name`, the name used would be `monte.screen.recorder`, as based on the jar name to module name mapping rule from the [ModuleFinder documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#of(java.nio.file.Path...)) linked by VGR in comments.

This is because the artifactId in the dependency is `monte-screen-recorder`, which indicates the jar name would be `monte-screen-recorder.jar`.

You can require the jar as a module in your `module-info.java` using:

```
requires monte.screen.recorder;
```

But this is what you already have, so it is not the usage of an incorrect module name that is causing your issue.

#### Recommendation: Make your project non-modular

You also have other dependencies that you aren't using as modules (e.g., `javacv` and `jaffree`).

When you have a lot of non-modular dependencies like this, I don't recommend making your application modular.  You experience a lot of the pain of using the module system, with few of its benefits realized.

Instead, run JavaFX and the core JDK off the module path (as that is how they are programmed to work), but make your application non-modular (delete the `module-info.java`).  The [Getting Started instructions at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) include information on various ways to develop non-modular applications using JavaFX technology.

Not using modules means that you can't link your application using `jlink`.  But, `jlink` does not work for automatic modules anyway, so your `jlink` configuration in your pom.xml cannot work regardless of whether your application is modular.

Comment: i am trying to develop no-moduler application but in my intellij idea facing javaFX SDK reated error i added javaFX SDK but still iam facing error @jewelsea

Error: Could not find or load main class java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

Comment: @AnupPanchal that is unrelated to your original question, please ask a new question.  Include the full command line being executed in the question and the error message as text, formatted as code.  If you are running the application in Idea by pressing the green run arrow, the command can be found in the console by clicking on it to expand it.

Comment: i am facing only this error 

java: module not found: monte.screen.recorder

no more error show in console  @jewelsea

Comment: Look the error message in your first comment and your second comment are different.  You can't expect help for different things that you add in comments, please don't ask it there.  I already explained in my answer that you can't use the jar that contains the screen recorder as a module and why that is so.